# DDoS prevention simulation

Tags: networking, simulation, ddos

To be specific I want to check feasibility and direction for my current semester project.
The scenario is ,i have attacker , my system , and victim server.Whatever DDoS traffic i wanna send must go through my system and then forward to victim server. I want to filter the traffic to check whether they are from legitimate users or infected PCS by checking and filtering packets and to allow access to only legitimate users.

Is it possible to design such scenario without routers (which can apply filters for this purpose) by sniffing packets through my system and check them and send request to victim server ? (i am thinking of victim should point or match there nameservers to ours for it)

is it possible to do it on single system by using multiple ips (localhost alike) to simulate this scenario?

Do i have use Winpcap for sniffing packets or there are any better solution or library available?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily recreate this scenario with use of virtual machines [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Simply install it, create a victim VM, couple attackers, configure them on a separate network which will be routed by another virtual machine which will "emulate" the router.
This is as close to replica of your described environment as you can get without additional hardware. It will take a bit of time and research to set up properly, but that is the point of studying.

Comment: Thank you sir. " It will take a bit of time and research to set up properly, but that is the point of studying." --- true it is.

Comment: yes i will but vote up require 15 reputation ...to have vote privileges

Comment: @GOT oh please don't take it the wrong way, and you can help to build a reputation by asking question and make sure to pick an answer that helped you most as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts as this way people are more likely to help you in the future!